# How do you get the Lunatic achievement?

Tags: achievements, ninjatown-trees-of-doom

Ninjatown: Trees of Doom has one achievement that I can't quite figure out.

[image: Lunatic achievement]

I'm guessing this is somehow related to the moon that is shown in the background when it is nighttime, but whenever I see the moon it's a crescent, never any other phase.

[image: Crescent moon at night]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I emailed the developers (Venan Entertainment) about this achievement, and got this response:

> The Lunatic achievement is a little evil on our part (and the name is
>   quite appropriate).
>
> As the game is now, once you reach 750 meters the day and night cycles
>   start. The moon always starts as full, but as the days and nights
>   cycle through the moon will continue to change phases.
>
> The simple answer is: Get above 750 meters then let the game just keep
>   running for a while. Once the game has cycled through approximately 12
>   days/nights you will get the Lunatic achievement.

Comment: I had imagined that something like this was the case, but then I thought "no, there's no way that they would do this". Looks like I was wrong.

Comment: My moon always starts at first quarter. I have cycled thru moon after moon to no avail.